# Использование new в перегруженном new

Tags: c++, память, перегрузка-операторов

В статье http://www.amse.ru/courses/cpp2/2011_03_21.html автор пишет:

> Рекомендуется не производить в операторе `new` (особенно в глобальном)
>   какие-либо операции с объектами, которые могут вызвать оператор `new`.
>   Например, для вывода текста использовать функцию `printf`, а не объект
>   `std::cout`.

С чем связана эта рекомендация? К каким неприятностям может привести ее нарушение?

Comment: Бесконечная рекурсия, например...

Comment: это единственная причина?

Comment: Неужели ее мало? :)

Comment: это про глобальный new? а не глобальный new тоже может вызвать бесконечную рекурсию?

Comment: Если вызовется для указанного типа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, смотрите: вот такой код

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int i):i(i){}

    void out() const { cout << "Test(" << i << ")\n"; }

    void * operator new(size_t sz);
    void operator delete(void * p);

private:
    int i;
};

void * Test::operator new(size_t sz)
{
    //return new Test(0);
    return malloc(sz);
}

void   Test::operator delete(void * p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

проблем не вызовет. Но стоит в операторе `new` раскомментировать одну строку и закомментировать вторую - как даже компилятор взбесится :) Просто он тут все видит, а вот если вызвать какую-то функцию опосредованно, из другого файла, которая вызовет `new Test` - то компилятор предупредить не сможет, и проблемы возникнут без предупреждения.

Особенно в случае глобального `new`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void* operator new(size_t n) {
    std::cout.put('a');
    return malloc(n);
}
```

Здесь обьект `std::cout` меняет свое состояние, а если в программе  этот обьект вызовит оператор, то это состояние будет "активизировано "

```
int main()
{    
    std::cout   << *(new char('b')) ;
    // ожидается вывод только символа 'b', но увы, выведится `ab`
    return  0;
}
```